# In mongoose how to push strings of array as documents of type sting?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am pushing an array of objects in mongoDB now i have array photos which have strings in it e.g photos = ["hii", "heee"] now my question is that when i am trying to push in mongoDB my whole array is being pushed in photos(field of a collection colection in mongoDB) fields like this photos[0] = ["hii", "hee"] but i want my photos array to push data like this photos[0] = "hii", photos[1] = "hee" my code is given below now can anyone pls tell me how to do that.

```
merchantphotosmodel.findOneAndUpdate({jeb_no: "yoo"}, {$addToSet: {photos: photos}}, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error Finding query results');
                console.log(err);
                res.json({success: 0, message : err});
                return next(err);
            } else {
                if (docs) {
                    var etc = new merchantphotosmodel({jeb_no: "ss", photos: { $each: photos}});
/* Here what to use to push wth each element */ etc.photos.push(photos);
                    etc.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error Inserting New Data');
                            if (err.name == 'ValidationError') {
                                for (field in err.errors) {
                                    console.log(err.errors[field].message);
                                }
                            }
                            console.log('bhak be');
                            res.json({success: 0, message : "fail to register"});
//                          throw err;
                            return next(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Succesfully Registered');
                            res.json({success : 1, message : "Succesfully Registered"});
                        }

                    }); 
                    console.log('ho gya');
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `{ $addToSet: { photos: { $each: photos } } }`.

Comment: yea it worked thx a lot but can you pls have a relook at the question?

Comment: The issue is at these lines, right?    

    `var etc = new merchantphotosmodel({jeb_no: "ss", photos: { $each: photos}});
    etc.photos.push(photos);`

`$each` is used when you request your database so here, you should just write:

    `var etc = new merchantphotosmodel({jeb_no: "ss", photos: photos});`